# Adding classes with dotnet CLI in VSCode

Tags: dotnet-cli, dotnetcorecli

I am new to dotnet core and I have tried to view the help of dotnet cli but does not seem to find an answer. How do we add a new class file to a dotnet core console app from dotnet CLI ?

Comment: I believe there's no such command, you should create file `Program.cs` manually in your file explorer, or in cli: `touch Program.cs` or `vim Program.cs`. Read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/cli-create-console-app

Comment: Thanks. I did create the file manually but since we have lots of commands to perform operations in cli hence wanted to know the possible way of adding a class with cli.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own custom templates for dotnet new (tutorial):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/cli-templates-create-item-template

A list of samples of varying complexity can be found here....

https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-template-samples

End of answer.

---

Non-answer

You didn't ask this but since vscode is a popular C# editor for people using dotnet new, if you happen to be using vscode you can create a new class file by typing e.g.

```
var myEye = new MyEye { color = "blue" };
```

Hit 'ctrl+.' over MyEye and select the option to create a new class in a file. You should see it created complete with properties and namespace.

Answer (score 2):

You can add class using this extension:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jchannon.csharpextensions

Answer (score 0):

One way that we can create a class from VSCode using a extension that is C# Extensions.
this will help to create a new class into our solution.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phDp1.png)